# How do I make Tkinter run an executable?

Tags: python, tkinter, embed, executable

I have an executable file, and I want to run it using Tkinter. How may I do this?

Comment: run it the same way as without `Tkinter `- use module `subprocess` or  `os.system()` or similar. With `Tkinter` you may have to also use `threading` if executed file is long-running process because long-running process could stop/freeze window in Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can run executable file using

```
import os

os.system("some_file.exe argument1 argument2")
```

but with this method you can't catch displayed text and use it in Python script.

There is also module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) which has many methods to run executable and catch text or not.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("some_file.exe argument1 argument2", shell=True)

subprocess.run(["some_file.exe", "argument1", "argument2"])
```

etc.

If executable file will run long time then it will stop tkinter's window - window will freeze -  so you would have to use module [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to run file in separated thread.